# Check if a string is same as a variable name

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
var x = "news";
```

and I have a variable

```
var news = array("1", "2", "3");
```

I really want to check if is there a variable have the same name with the string "news", in this case, it will return true because there is a variable name `news`

Can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: For the general case, it's barely possible using some really ugly tricks, but it definitely shouldn't be done. Variable names should be completely static.

Comment: You can only do this with global variables, because they become properties in `window`. But why do you need to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, variables are part of basic JavaScript.

Comment: `window.hasOwnProperty(x)` x is your string variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the keys of `this` and check for a var name

```js
var x = "news"
var news = ["1", "2", "3"]

function varNameExists(varName){
    return [...Object.keys(this)].some(name => name === varName)
}

console.log(varNameExists(x))
```

Comment: After checking, if it exists, how can I use the string as that variable name.
For example, if that variable exists, how can I call the `news` array?

Comment: @LuuHoangBac window[x] or eval(x)

Answer (score 2):

You can check with `window.hasOwnProperty` but this is not proper way.

```js
var x="news";
var news=["1","2","3"];
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty(x))

x="nxyz";

console.log(window.hasOwnProperty(x))

x="news";

console.log(window.hasOwnProperty(x))
```

Comment: After checking, if it exists, how can I use the string as that variable name. For example, if that variable exists, how can I call the `news` array?